# Bulk Container image pull without "docker pull"

Tags: docker, containers

Is there any way we can download container images without using docker pull.
I want to ship multiple containers to different environments which do not have internet access.

Currently I am following

1. Download image one by image using docker pull command
2. docker save image.tar
3. Copy tar to destination
4. docker load

Answer (score 0):

If your images depends one from another, a trick would be to do a `docker run` of the most complex image (the one built on top of the others): that would trigger a `docker pull` of all the images FROM which the complex one is built.

But for unrelated images, you would still need to pull them individually.

I don't know of a way to save *all* image beside a script.
See for instance [`save-all-images.sh`](https://gist.github.com/lalyos/50ac584bf0dc6ccb061f) from [lalyos](https://github.com/lalyos).

```
save-all-image() {
  local ids=$(docker images -q)
  local name safename tag

  for id in $ids; do
    name=$(get-image-name $id)
    tag=$(get-image-tag $id)
    if [[  $name =~ / ]] ; then
       dir=${name%/*}
       mkdir -p $dir
    fi
    echo [DEBUG] save $name:$tag ...
    (time  docker save -o $name.$tag.dim $name:$tag) 2>&1|grep real
  done
}
```

Comment: Thanks VonC. Mainly I was looking for script which can do this job. How do we take backup of registry ? won't this will help